# C++ code compilation fatal error: xdo.h: No such file or directory

Tags: 18.04, c++

I am using **Ubuntu 18.04** on **Dell Vostro 15 - 3546**.

```
uname -api
Linux vaishnavi-laptop 4.15.0-118-generic #119-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 8 12:30:01 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I want to install `comfortable-swipe`. This is my output of `bash install`:

```
Installing binaries ...
./comfortable-swipe-main.cpp:31:10: fatal error: xdo.h: No such file or directory
 #include <xdo.h>
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Is there any way fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This compilation needs `xdo.h` to be installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libxdo-dev
```

Hope this helps.